# Twitter SSL error when trying to fetch data

Tags: ssl, twitter, oauth-2.0

I am trying to fetch data from twitter but i get secure connection error when i try to fetch from http://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json. This happens after i've set the tokens with Oauth.

Error Looks like this: {"errors":[{"message":"SSL is required","code":92}]}

Code:

```
$oauth = new OAuth( OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
$oauth->enableDebug();



if (!isset( $_GET['oauth_token'] ) && !isset($_SESSION['token']) )
{
    $request_token = $oauth->getRequestToken( OAUTH_REQUEST_URL, CALLBACK_URL );
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

    header('Location: '. OAUTH_AUTHORISE_URL .'?oauth_token='.$request_token['oauth_token']);
}

if ( isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_GET['oauth_verifier']) )
{
    $oauth->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
    $access_token = $oauth->getAccessToken( OAUTH_ACCESS_URL );

    $_SESSION['token'] = serialize( $access_token );


    header('location: http://local.oauth.com/twitter/callback.php');
}


$access_token = unserialize($_SESSION['token']);

    echo  $access_token['oauth_token'] . ' <br/> ' . $access_token['oauth_token_secret'];

$oauth->setToken( $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret'] );
$oauth->fetch( API_URL . 'account/verify_credentials.json' );
```

Does anyone know why and how could i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

As the message states

> SSL is required

You need to connect to

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json
```

not

```
http://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json
```